# Hover on a link and change the background-image of a div - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseover

I'm having trouble making a div's background-image change when hovering over a link the code looks fine to me so I'm at a loss here is the code:

Javascript:

```
   $('#hover-01').on('mouseover', function(){
   $('#hover-change').css('background-image', 'url("images/1.jpg")');
});
$('#hover-01').on('mouseout', function(){, function(){
  $('#hover-change').css('background-image', 'url("images/5.jpg")');
});
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="open-project-link">
    <a id="hover-01" class="open-project"  
   href="project3.html">Bowman Clay</a>
    </div>


<div class="responsive-section-image" id="hover-change" 
 style="background-image: url(images/5.jpg);">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
                         </div>
```

jQuery version: v2.1.1

Any idea's or advice?

Edit: the code does work however it was a problem with a 3rd party plugin (I assume) so I fixed it with normal javascript and not jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'`mousein`' isn't an event handler that you can use. You should use `mouseover` and `mouseout`, or `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. See jQuery mouse events [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/).

You also need to give a width/height to your container that will hold the image, since it has no contents. Also, you have two `function()` declarations in your mouseout function, I fixed it in the following code sample:

```js
  $('#hover-01').on('mouseenter', function(){
   $('#hover-change').css('background-image', 'url(http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg)');
});
$('#hover-01').on('mouseleave', function(){
  $('#hover-change').css('background-image', 'url(https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/leisa_christmas_false_color.png?itok=Jxf0IlS4)');
});
```

```css
#hover-change {
  width:1000px;
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="open-project-link">
    <a id="hover-01" class="open-project"  
   href="project3.html">Bowman Clay</a>
    </div>


<div class="responsive-section-image" id="hover-change">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Nick G I have tried a while ago the mouseover and it doesn't seem to want to work I have even copied and pasted your code just to make sure and it stil doesn't work sadly

Comment: @ChrisLad I fixed it in my edit. There's a working example.

Comment: It should work but how ever when i try to put it to the site it doesn't work and says $ is not defined the only thing i can think of is maybe another plugin messing it up because everything seems fine code wise to me and i see it working on fiddle

Comment: if it says `$ is not defined` that means that you haven't linked a jQuery library to your code.

Comment: @ChrisLad There's a problem with how you're linking jQuery then. Assuming you have jQuery in the js folder, try changing your script to either `<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>` or `<script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: I have other js functions that are working fine so the library is linked correctly

Comment: @ChrisLad Make sure jQuery is the first script loaded also. If any other js files use `$()` without jQuery already being rendered, then you'll get that error.

Comment: The error has gone but it still does not work i've copied everything to the T this is really strange it has to be a plugin I am using or something

Comment: @ChrisLad Definitely could be. Here's a question with the same problem, maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined

Comment: @ChrisLad let me know if you need any other advice, I'll try but can't guarantee since I can't see your setup.

Comment: I went down the old javascript rather than jQuery way to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/mugddzxk/#&togetherjs=vHK7fB545n):

JS:

```
$('#hover-01').on('mouseenter', function(){
   $('#hover-change').css('background-image', 'url("images/1.jpg")');
});
$('#hover-01').on('mouseout', function(){
  $('#hover-change').css('background-image', 'url("images/5.jpg")');
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply for some reason when I try this I'm getting Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(…) and it does not work how ever i can see it working in the fiddle this is confusing I have copied and pasted the code exactly

Comment: That is because you didn't link a jQuery library.

Comment: Please link the `jQuery` library

Comment: I'm currently running jQuery v2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method to solve your problem like this:

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  
  $('#link').on('mouseover', function() {
    //alert('sadasd');
    $('body').toggleClass('colored');
  });
  
  $('#link').on('mouseleave', function() {
    //alert('sadasd');
    $('body').toggleClass('colored');
  });
  
});
```

```css
body.colored {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a id="link" href="#">This is a Link</a>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS `:hover ~` to change the `hover-change` div when `hover-01` is hovered over as follows:

```
#divToHover:hover ~ #divToChange {
  /*your code here*/
}
```

```css
#change {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-image: url("//www.google.com/favicon.ico");
}
#hover {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-color: green;
}
#hover:hover ~ #change {
  background-image: url(/favicon.ico);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hover">hover</div>
<div id="change"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. Make sure to set height and width for the div for which you want the background change.

Issue was with your event name used. Refer [here](http://jqfundamentals.com/chapter/events) for list of mouse events

```js
$('#hover-01').on('mouseover', function() {
     $('#hover-change').css('background-image', 'url("https://placehold.it/350x150/ffff00")');
   }).on('mouseout', function() {
     $('#hover-change').css('background-image', 'url("https://placehold.it/350x150/ff0000")');
   });
```

```css
.responsive-section-image {
  height: 150px;
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="open-project-link">
  <a id="hover-01" class="open-project" href="project3.html">Bowman Clay</a>
</div>

<div class="responsive-section-image" id="hover-change" style="background-image: url('https://placehold.it/350x150/ff0000')">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```